# Why could document.querySelector() be returning null in this case?

Tags: javascript, queryselector

What could cause `queryselector` to not find an element in such a scenario

```
function load_home(){
    //this function has a lot of fetch calls and creates a lot of divs
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    load_home();

    let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div"); //doesnt contain any of the divs that should have                 been created
    console.log("Count", divs.length); 
})
```

i have something similar to the above.... i call a function, `load_home` when the DOM is loaded that creates some divs... on the next line i try to count the divs on the page... but i cant find all the divs that have been created in `load_home` ...

assuming  `load home` functions properly, and i properly query for all the divs on the page, what could cause me to not find the divs created in `load_home` ?

really, i want to know if there are any feature in javascript that could cause such a thing ie and I'm just making stuff up here maybe functions with fetch calls run on another thread (dont even really know what these are) and as such `load_home` might not be done yet or the `DOMContentLoaded` has some weird feature that wont let what I'm doing work or maybe fetch calls cause some unexpected behaviour or created stuff cant be accessed normally in EventListeners ?....

Comment: Maybe it's because your `fetch()` calls don't complete before `load_home()` returns because **`fetch()` is asynchronous**.

Comment: but since the `fetch` calls are inside `load_home` shouldn't all of them finish before the next line is run ie `let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");`? also , functions can return before what is in them is finished?

Comment: @daultimateboss can you provide the code of fetching data? it's hard to tell if we don't know how the html is generated.

Comment: @daultimateboss no. And yes, functions can return before asynchronous operations started from within them have finished; that's kind-of the whole point.

Comment: *"but since the fetch calls are inside load_home shouldn't all of them finish before the next line is run"*: the  `fetch` calls themselves obviously return, but the *responses* come only later, asynchronously, i.e. when the call stack is empty. Your `load_home` function will thus return before *any* of the responses are available.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `load_home()` function asynchronous and awaiting it before `document.querySelectorAll('div')`.

```
async function load_home() {
    //this function has a lot of fetch calls and creates a lot of divs
    // Also remember to add `await` keyword before calling `fetch()`
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    await load_home();

    let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div"); 
    console.log("Count", divs.length); 
});
```

Also you can use something like this:

```
function load_home() {
    // Example fetch call
    fetch('https://example.com/api/data')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Process data and create divs
            createDivs();
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

function createDivs() {
    // Create divs here

    // Now, call the function that relies on the created divs
    countDivs();
}

function countDivs() {
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    console.log("Count", divs.length);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    load_home();
});
```